# How do i build joomla 1.5 modules with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, joomla, module, joomla1.5

I need to build a news scroller module for a website in Joomla (http://www.expedicionantioquia.org/idures/index.php) to replace the one made with flash on the right column. I was thinking on doing it with JQuery to allow the tabbed navigation, but i'm a little bit lost, partly because i haven't found a good tutorial about building joomla modules.

I know there's a file structure which represents the MVC pattern, but i would like to do it as simple as posible, somehting like skipping all that and just displaying the required html. The problem is that it's a little more complicated than just using a custom html module. I need to get some parameters which would be the news, with their titles and picture paths from the joomla admin, is it posible to do that without having anything to do with the database? Also, how do i include libraries like JQuery for my module?

If anyone knows about a good tutorial where these topics are covered please do tell :) Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources to get you started:

**jQuery and Joomla**

[Using jQuery with Joomla!](http://www.sanjeevshrestha.com.np/2009/05/using-jquery-with-joomla/)
[More on using jQuery with Joomla](http://leland.dormsdocs.info/index.php?/more-on-using-jquery-with-joomla)

**Module Development:**

[Tutorial:Creating a Hello World Module for Joomla 1.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial:Creating_a_Hello_World_Module_for_Joomla_1.5)
[Module Development in Joomla](http://www.packtpub.com/article/module-development-in-joomla)

Answer (score 0):

Follow what sarfaz said.
Also you can go for a detailed browsing in http://extensions.joomla.org/

Most probably the module that you are looking for is available already , and you can get it set with minimal customisation instead of totally re inventing the wheel.

Availability of a rich set of components & modules is one big advantage in using joomla.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to include jquery library files is as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```